# Pointer to std::vector, pointer declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Are there any differences between these two pointer declarations to pass a std::vector to a function that has a special signature that I don't really understand?

```
libraryFunction (int numSamples, double* const* arrayOfChannels) { 
  //things
}

std::vector<double> theVectorA = {11, 22, 33, 44};
double * p_VecA[1];
p_VecA[0] = theVectorA.data();
libraryFunction(theVectorA.size(), p_VecA);

std::vector<double> theVectorB = {55, 66, 77};
double * p_VecB = theVectorB.data();
libraryFunction(theVectorB.size(), p_VecB);
```

What are the differences between p_VecA and p_VecB?

Can you explain the function signature? I don't understand the last part.

Comment: p_VecA is double** while p_VecB is double*

Comment: You mean besides the fact that `p_VecA` is an ***array*** of pointers, and that `p_VecB` is not?

Comment: Regarding the pointer, the general recommendation is to read it using the spiral rule, so `arrayOfChannels` is a pointer to a `const` pointer to double.

Comment: So the correct way is to use the p_VecA option because the function signature requires the array of pointers. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double * p_VecA[1];` creates an array of 1 pointer element, which points to a `double` (in this case, the first `double` in `theVectorA`). Therefore `p_VecA` is an array of pointers to doubles, in this context if you use the name without index it decays to a pointer to its first element (think of it as `double**`) and `p_VecA[0]` is of type `double*` (like `p_VecB` is).

`double * p_VecB` creates a pointer to a `double` (in this case, the first `double` in `theVectorB`).

#### Update:

Maybe this can help you to understand the signature of `libraryFunction()`:

[What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/)

Like Jack wrote: `arrayOfChannels` is a pointer to a const pointer to double

Comment: Thanks! so in this case the correct way is the first option, p_VecA, and the other is incorrect, right?

Comment: `Therefore p_VecA is of type double**` no it isn't. It is an array; not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks you are right. I claryfied that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

p_vecA is an array of pointers with size 1

```
double * p_VecA[1];
```

p_VecB is pointer

```
double * p_VecB = theVectorB.data();
```

Can be written as

```
double * p_VecB;
p_VecB = theVectorB.data();
```

Comment: It's not homework. I have to work with that function but I don't understand the function signature: libraryFunction(int numSamples, double * const * arrayOfChannels). I wrote the first code (p_VecA two years ago and I don't remember why I did it like this, I was thinking that p_VecA and p_VecB were the same, my bad

Comment: Ha ha everyone made mistakes. Good luck with your wokr